# Ajax Post Data Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Hi besides a jquery function, i want to submit the input formfield of #dropdownbox1 with the ajax post too...please take a look:

The function foo.crop  will return an object that contains the width, height, and image string + data type:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: foo.crop(846, 846, 'png') 
    })
    .done(function(data) {

            // do stuff after image is saved
 alert( "Okay!" );
    });
```

process.php recieving the variables:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {



    $img = str_replace('data:image/'.$_POST['type'].';base64,', '', $_POST['string']);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
```

how can i add the #dropdown value to the data to send it to process.php ?

maybe if it helps, here is the  crop function with the returns:

```
this.crop = function(width, height, type) {

        ....

            return {
                width: width,
                height: height,
                type: type || 'png',
                string: canvas.toDataURL("image/" + type || 'png'),
            };

        };
```

please help im quiet new to jquery and i need to get this script work!

TRIED THAT:

```
var data = {
    imageData: foo.crop(846, 846, 'png'),
    dropdown: $("#dropdownbox1").val()
};
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: data
});
```

but it didnt work ;(

Answer (score 0):

In the data attribute, just pass an object where each key is the name you want to use on the server and the values are the values from your form

```
var data = {
    imageData: image,
    dropdown: $("#dropdownbox1").val()
};
$.ajax({
 type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: data
});
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: $('body').on("click", '.saveimage', function () {
$.ajax({
 var data = {
    imageData: foo.crop(846, 846, 'png'),
    dropdown: $("#imagethumb").val()
};
 
 
  type: "post",
  url: "process.php",
  data: data,
   
 })
 .done(function(data) {
 
   // do stuff after image is saved
 alert( "Okay!" );
 });
 
 
});

Comment: Can you put any code updates in your question please? It's near impossible to read in these comments

Comment: Did you try exactly what I wrote? I'm just giving you an example, those aren't the actual values to use.

Comment: yes i didnt worked for me ...the problem is i dont know how to handle the returned values of the crop function and add the dropdown value to the data...

Comment: What I showed you above will add the dropdown data, for your image, what are you using? If you're trying to upload the image via ajax you need to create a new FormData object and attach it to that, then send that along

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 2 parameters to the data attribute like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {
                "image":foo.crop(846, 846, 'png'),
                "select": $("#dropdownbox1").val()
          }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
            // do stuff after image is saved
 alert( "Okay!" );
    });
```

You can then access these on your process.php page. 
Print the post array as `print_r($_POST)` to ensure you get the expected values.